# Get DB data and fill the title attribute for tooltip in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am struggling on how the bootstrap tooltip's title attribute's text data can be retrieved and shown through the captured data from database.

I have already captured the row data for my table using $http and correctly show my table data, I want to use the data as my tooltip data too

[image]

Here, I can successfully use ng-repeat to loop through my rowData, but my rowData also contains the tooltip data for each td, how can I modify the tooltip text attribute in order to show tooltip data?

The following is my controller on how to get the rowData
[image]

Thanks all for the kind help

Sorry for missing some info, I actually write a directive specifically for the tooltip as follows
[image]

The cellData variable is from the rowData which is come from the pData, the pData comes from the data read from DB using GET method

Comment: If you are able to get the data inside ng-repeat why are you not a able to use it directly? What errors are you getting.

Comment: Ahaaan I got the exact issue you are facing. You should be using the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end that should help to achieve what you are trying. Read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @CoderJohn Thanks for the reply, but I need to put the cellData into the title attribute, but angularjs doesn't seem to allow me to do so, it just output the text {{cellData}}.

Comment: See if you can add plunker/jsfiddle link by using your code that comes from db. u just declare one object and assign returned data to it, just like myobj=[{paste ur db data}]; keep your code minimal n working so that people can play with your code, you will get your solution.

Comment: But where does the cellData variable come from ? I can't see it initialised anywhere in the code nor does it reference from ng-repeat loop?

Comment: cellData is just a variable for ng-repeat @CoderJohn ..

Comment: @Sudarshan Thanks for the suggest, I will try to see if I can make it in JSFiddle

Comment: welcome please see it works as you need or not

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with nested ng-repeat & their $scope, but if the data is coming in your tr td then you need to work little different to get your tooltip. I am providing you a simple tooltip example see if you can modify your code according to it, It works with BS tooltip. below i have pasted my code, also see this demo [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XTG8k/5/)

```
html code
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <table class="table" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>column</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span tooltip="that">this</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="foo in bar">
                <td><span tooltip="{{foo.tooltip}}">{{foo.content}}</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body> 

app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.bar = [];
    // doing something async (exec time simulated by setTimeout)
    myAsyncFunc(function (bar) {

        $scope.$apply(function() {
             $scope.bar = bar;
        });
    });

}]);

var myAsyncFunc = function (done) {
    // simulate some kind of timeout due to processing of the function
    setTimeout(function () {
        return done([{tooltip: 'this is the tooltip', content: 'this is the content'}]);
    }, 500);
};
```